# Jargon related to making rope?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a more specific verb that describes creating rope than "make"? E.g. braid or weave or is the verb choice specific to the type of rope that is being made?

Is there a word for a person that makes rope other than "rope maker", e.g. as a cooper is to barrel making?

Comment: A rope is "made" by "twisting" together strands of hemp or similar material. The word "ropemaker" exists in English since the fifteenth century (OED), from Dutch origin. Hence it would seem that "make" is the only general descriptive verb in rope manufacture.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From http://www.the-ropewalk.co.uk/ks2th2.pdf, pages 9 and 10:

Raw fibres are **hatchelled** into long straight clean fibres, which are **spun** into yarn, which is **twisted** into strands, which are **twisted** into rope.

Different types of rope are made with different numbers of strands (page 14).

Rope makers are generally called rope makers - there is a detailed explanation of the processes involved at the [Barton Ropery Museum](http://www.ropewalkmuseum.co.uk/2012/09/25/the-story-of-halls-barton-ropery/).